# SQL using with clause not working

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My question is why this query does not work?

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_staff WHERE PMajor = '%" + spin.getSelectedItem().toString() + "%'", null);
```

`Cursor c`: it is a cursor for handling my query   
`tbl_staff`: my table that consist of `PName`, `PMajor`, `PCert`   
`spin`: is spinner that has values which I need for my database query.

When I use:

```
if (c.moveToNext())
else (log.d("error query","couldn't do the query!");)
```

It goes to `else` statement and `moveToNext()` doesn't work.

Comment: Did you exec the moveToFirst() method first?

Comment: what do you mean? if you mean using it in if statement and having some codes then yes

Comment: As per http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html , you should call moveToFirst() to place the cursor on the first entry.

Comment: indeed, I have put moveToFirst() but still no result.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `=`, which checks for equality, use keyword `LIKE`, which matches a pattern.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_staff WHERE PMajor LIKE '%" + spin.getSelectedItem().toString() + "%'", null);
```